# Updating column for more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a single SQL command which will update table 'name', where the column 'id' matches 'eg1', 'eg2' and 'eg3'. The column to be updated is 'status' and should be changed to 'new_status' for the previously specified ids only.

Unfortunately I'm new with SQL, therefore I only got as far as this which doesn't seem to be working:

```
SELECT * FROM `tblhosting` WHERE 'id' IN (eg1,eg2,eg3) UPDATE 'status' SET new_status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Update tblhosting set status = 'new_status' where id in ('eg1','eg2','eg3')
```

This assuems you want to update tblhosting column status set to 'new_status' where the ID is either eg1, eg2 or eg3.

Answer (score 1):

String literals are enclosed in single quotes.

Identifiers can be optionally enclosed in backtick characters.

The syntax for an `UPDATE` statement is like this:

```
  UPDATE `tblhosting`
     SET `status` = 'new_status'
   WHERE `id` IN ('eg1','eg2','eg3')
```

The specification is a little ambiguous. The example above searches the table named `tblhosting` for rows to be updated, and assigns a value to the `status` column.  This assumes that the value to be assigned is a string literal `"new_status"`, and that `"eg1"`, `"eg2"` and `"eg3"` are string values found in the column named `id`.)

Answer (score 0):

update `tblhosting` set new_status = 'status' WHERE 'id' IN (eg1,eg2,eg3)